# Thinkpad T60 display has suddenly gone dim

Tags: display, lcd, thinkpad, backlight, laptop-display

I have an IBM Thinkpad T60 2007 laptop with a 14-inch 1024x768 screen. Some time ago on one occasion I turned it on, Windows booted without any problems, but in the exact moment I plugged in my webcam (Logitech C905) the display went totally dim - the picture was still there but no backlight.

Could the webcam or the USB port I was plugging it into have caused this? I'm using that port all the time and it's working fine.

Since then I have ordered and changed the following components:

- inverter (twice)
- LCD panel
- display ribbon cable

but neither of those has helped.

I've been using my TV as a display since the light went out and it works totally fine, but I'd really like to use it as a portable computer again.

I've run out of ideas, does anyone have anything that could help?

Comment: Sounds like the motherboard power section has failed.

Comment: That doesn't sound too good, would that mean the motherboard needs to be replaced?

Comment: That is my guess, unless you got another bad panel or inverter.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll have a look around if there are any system boards available then.

Comment: Here is a good forum for Thinkpads, you might ask for diagnostic help there also...http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewforum.php?f=29

Comment: I already ordered a replacement system board from ebay but I'll check it out if still no luck, cheers!

Comment: It looks like the system board was the culprit. I replaced it with tho one ordered from ebay and now it works fine. Thanks for the tip!